# Android battery level

Tags: android, battery

I have a problem with an application that sends coordinates via SMS.
When I added the battery level, the application stopped working after catching the fix.
(Coordinates not on display, but they are via SMS.)

Please help.

**ZoltrixGPSActivity**

```
package com.zoltrix.gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ZoltrixGPSActivity extends Activity {

    // Here I added a level of battery (1)

    private TextView contentTxt;
    private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
            contentTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
        }
    };

    // end

    TextView textLat;
    TextView textLong;
    TextView textAlt;
    TextView textPro;
    TextView textAcc;
    TextView textSpeed;
    public String onLocat;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Here I added a level of battery (2)

        contentTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.battery);
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

        // end

        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonExit);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // exit
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLat);
        textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLong);
        textAlt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAlt);
        textPro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPro);
        textAcc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAcc);
        textSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSpeed);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    }

    class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                double pLat = location.getLatitude();
                double pAlt = location.getAltitude();
                String PPro = location.getProvider();
                float PAcc = location.getAccuracy();
                float PSpeed = location.getSpeed();

                textLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
                textLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
                textAlt.setText(Double.toString(pAlt));
                textPro.setText(PPro);
                textAcc.setText(Float.toString(PAcc));
                textSpeed.setText(Double.toString(PSpeed));

                Intent i = new Intent(ZoltrixGPSActivity.this,
                        SendSMSActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("lon", Double.toString(pLong));
                i.putExtra("lat", Double.toString(pLat));
                i.putExtra("alt", Double.toString(pAlt));
                i.putExtra("acc", Float.toString(PAcc));
                i.putExtra("spe", Float.toString(PSpeed));
                startActivity(i);

            }

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

**SendSMSActivity**

```
package com.zoltrix.gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnSendSMS;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

                String LON = extras.getString("lon");
                String LAT = extras.getString("lat");
                String ALT = extras.getString("alt");
                String ACC = extras.getString("acc");
                String SPE = extras.getString("spe");

                sendSMS("510104727", "LON" + LON + "#" + "LAT" + LAT + "#"
                        + "ALT" + ALT + "#" + "ACC" + ACC + "#" + "SPE" + SPE);
            }

        });
    }

    // ---sends an SMS message to another device---
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zoltrix.gps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.zoltrix.gps.SendSMSActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zoltrix.gps.ZoltrixGPSActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Loyout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Latitude"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Longitude "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Alt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAlt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Provider"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Accuracy (m)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAcc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text344"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Speed (m/s)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSpeed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/battery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendSMS"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonExit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat**
http://pastebin.com/whhdHsyw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `android.permission.BATTERY_STATS` permission to your code.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
```

Comment: thank you , it helped, but does not show coordinates on the screen. When the phone catches  fixs there for a second and disappear with text of the battery level.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Put this Code into your MainActivity where you want to show level

private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        int level = i.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        pb.setProgress(level);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfield);
        tv.setText("Battery Level: " + Integer.toString(level) + "%");
    }

};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    registerReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}
// Please Add the given below code into manifest:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
```